# Includes specific .css conditionally with web pack

Tags: css, webpack

I have a web application built with webpack. I have many styling variations, and those styles are all called style.css and in their own respective directories like

- ./STYLE_A/style.scss
- ./STYLE_B/style.scss
- ./STYLE_F/style.scss

  I am supplying a cross-env variable STYLE_DIR to webpack and I want that variable to control where the scss gets included from.

I've tried:

```
require(`./${STYLE_DIR}/style.scss`); //in the webpack (does nothing)
```

I've tried:

```
require(`./${STYLE_DIR}/style.scss`); //in my client.js (ends up including every style.scss from every one of the style directories)
```

I've tried setting this to a 'process.env' variable in webpack, I've tried using an alias to resolve, there's something I'm just missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got interested in your question, then I did a little research and I think I have a way to make it work.

Steps:

1.
In Webpack config file use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) in order to have a constant that can be setup at compile time. You do that in this way:

```
const GLOBALS = {
  'process.env.STYLE_DIR': JSON.stringify(process.env.STYLE_DIR)
};

export default {
  entry: [
    './app/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS)
  ],
  ...
}
```

2.
Put your style.scss file in the correct folders (STYLE_A, STYLE_B and STYLE_C as you indicated).

3.
In your .js file require your SCSS file as follow (of course be sure to have the corresponding loaders properly setup in Webpack config file):

```
require(`./${process.env.STYLE_DIR}/style.scss`);
```

4.
Set the STYLE_DIR variable before you run webpack. Something like this:

export STYLE_DIR = 'STYLE_A'

This is working for me. If I change the STYLE_DIR value before running Webpack I get a different style file imported.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I think it's correct.
Unfortunately, I'm always getting all of the .scss files concatenated in my final .css, so I thinks something else is sweeping the directories and gobbling up / including the .scss files. I need to do some more digging.